Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') in devtools extension, manifest3

I'm trying to follow https://betterprogramming.pub/chrome-extension-intercepting-and-reading-the-body-of-http-requests-dd9ebdf2348b to create a devtools panel in order to grab the response of a specific post request on a website. I've started with the instructions in the second part of the article, to create a basic devtools panel (which appears to work). I followed this with a discussion of the devtools.network API at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/devtools/network#type-Request
Here is the manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Description",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html"
}

devtools.html:
<script src="devtools.js"></script>

devtools.js:
chrome.devtools.panels.create("MyPanel", null, 'panel.html');

panel.html:
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="panel.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

panel.js:
function handleRequestFinished(request) {
  request.getContent((content, mimeType) => {
    console.log("Content: ", content);
    console.log("MIME type: ", mimeType);
  });
}

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(handleRequestFinished);

I'm getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Since there is no then in your code you look at an old error for your old code. Remove it by clicking the trashcan icon.
